# Getting error cordova.file undefined

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

As per 'Platform-centered workflow' from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html created a project with help of https://github.com/apache/cordova-android repository on local (cordova version: 5.1.0-dev)
Used plugman to add file plug-in into project but getting error  cordova.file object is undefined while accessing it in console or alert. cordova object is coming successfully in any dialog box.
Tried with following to solve it but no of use:
github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file@4.0.0

All the entries into config.xml file and AndroidManifest.xml are correct after adding any way to add plug-in.
Please suggest anyone to help this.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure cordova.file pluging has added to project ?

if yes, make sure you called cordova.file after device is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

and also **cordova.file is not working on emulator.** (in my experience)

Comment: i am sure to add cordova.file plugin(through plugman) and accessed it after device ready by cordova. Test on device also but no of use.
As per 'Platform-centered workflow' i use plugman so i suppose this is not copying or adding respective file to assets/www folder from 'platform_www'. Once i copied it manually to this said folder then it work for cordova.file object. Not sure what's happening with plugman use but  now change to CLI based project so adding correctly plugins and working fine.